# Как подключать сторонние библиотеки C/C++ в VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Нашёл кучу информации о том, как подключать сторонние библиотеки C/C++ к Microsoft VS, но ничего про Visual Studio Code. Редактор сильно отличается, руководств в интернете совсем немного(про сторонние библиотеки вообще ни одного не нашёл), очень хочу поработать в этом редакторе, но никак не могу разобраться, как же подсоединить к проекту внешнюю библиотеку. Желательно показать на примере библиотеки SFML или OpenGL.

Буду крайне благодарен за хоть какой-нибудь ответ!

Comment: Первое что попалось https://www.programmersought.com/article/1263524392/

Comment: а какой отношение имеют подключаемые библиотеки к редактору? Используйте например `cmake` для построения зависимость и не привязывайте себя цепью к редактору

Comment: VS поставляется со своим компилятором, поэтому для нее и инструкции по подключению библиотек отдельные. VSC сама по себе не связана ни с каким компилятором. Гуглите не про VSC, а про ваш компилятор (скорее всего MinGW GCC), и разберитесь как компилировать код с библиотеками в командной строке. Потом сможете вписать ту же команду в настройки VSC, и все.

Answer (score -1):

> Нашёл кучу информации о том, как подключать сторонние библиотеки C/C++ к Microsoft VS, но ничего про Visual Studio Code.

Посмотрите это.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
Статья от первоисточника "Using GCC with MinGW"

Цитирую в машинном переводе:

> В этом руководстве вы настраиваете Visual Studio Code для использования компилятора GCC C (g) и отладчика GDB из mingw-w64 для создания программ, работающих в Windows. После настройки VS Code вы скомпилируете и отладите простую программу Hello World в VS Code.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В вашем виде ответ скорее всего будет удален. Ответы-ссылки становятся бесполезными, если ссылка станет не активной или информация по ней изменится. Добавьте основные тезисы и пояснения в ответ,  а ссылку оставьте только в виде источника информации

Comment: Немного не в ту степь. Автор спросил про сторонние библиотеки, а не просто про С++ в VSC.

Comment: точно, сорян...